# C# Stopwatch on-the-fly update

Tags: c#, keydown, stopwatch

(My first question here!)
Hi, I am kind of beginner in c#. I tried to build a simple timer (in Windows.Forms).
I made a label which indicates the time, and used the StopWatch class (from system.diagnostics). The trigger event for starting / stopping the stopwatch is the spacebar KeyDown event. After the second tap the stopwatch stops and Label.text is assigned to the Stopwatch.Elapsed value. I want to continuously update the label, but I don't know how.
If I make `while(StopWatchName.IsRunning)` in the event itself, the event will indefinitely continue and won't respond for the second tap.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should probably have a [timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx) which fires frequently (e.g. every 10ms) - start the timer when you start the stopwatch, and stop the timer when you stop the stopwatch. The timer tick event would just set the label's `Text` property from the stopwatch.

The timer's interval won't be *exact* of course - but that's okay, because the point is to rely on the stopwatch for the actual timing. The timer is just there to update the label frequently.

Comment: Why is it my own point of view that using Timer is condemned to fail? What I have not understood well? Thanks in advance! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16496309/stopwatch-loop-using-vb-net

Comment: @Novemberland: You're missing the fact that the resolution of the timer doesn't matter at all. So long as it refreshes the screen "fairly frequently", that's fine - it's the `Stopwatch` which is responsible for being accurate.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to want to use System.Timers. Timer class in order to call a function every few seconds to update your UI with the time elapased value.

Here is a good Sample:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Basically, your OnTimedEvent event function from the sample is what will accomplish thisin your code.

EDIT: John is correct (see comments) you should be using Forms.Timer you can avoid thread marshaling.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx

TimerEventProcessor would be the function of concern in that sample.

Comment: It would be better to use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`, which will automatically fire on the UI thread, so there's no need to either set a synchronizing object or use `Control.Invoke`.

Answer (score 0):

The following example instantiates a System.Timers.Timer object that fires its Timer.Elapsed event every two seconds (2,000 milliseconds), sets up an event handler for the event, and starts the timer. The event handler displays the value of the ElapsedEventArgs.SignalTime property each time it is raised. ([document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1))

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

public class Example
{
   private static System.Timers.Timer aTimer;

   public static void Main()
   {
      SetTimer();

      Console.WriteLine("\nPress the Enter key to exit the application...\n");
      Console.WriteLine("The application started at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}", DateTime.Now);
      Console.ReadLine();
      aTimer.Stop();
      aTimer.Dispose();

      Console.WriteLine("Terminating the application...");
   }

   private static void SetTimer()
   {
        // Create a timer with a two second interval.
        aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(2000);
        // Hook up the Elapsed event for the timer. 
        aTimer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        aTimer.AutoReset = true;
        aTimer.Enabled = true;
    }

    private static void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Elapsed event was raised at {0:HH:mm:ss.fff}",
                          e.SignalTime);
    }
}
// The example displays output like the following:
//       Press the Enter key to exit the application...
//
//       The application started at 09:40:29.068
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:31.084
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:33.100
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:35.100
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:37.116
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:39.116
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:41.117
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:43.132
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:45.133
//       The Elapsed event was raised at 09:40:47.148
//
//       Terminating the application...
```