# Implement a pausable, "ticking" stopwatch

Tags: c#, .net

I want stopwatch functionality that either:

- Allows for start/stop/pause/reset;
- Notifies its elapsed time periodically at a prescribed interval (typically one second), so that I can refresh a UI sopwatch display;

If I use `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`, I can start/stop/pause/reset, and I can query (pull) its elapsed time, but I don't have the "one second elapsed" (push) event;

If I use `System.Timers.Timer`, I can attach to the `Elapsed` event, but `Stop` won't actually stop time counting, instead just stopping to raise the `Elapsed` event.

**Q:**

- Is there any class that could give me both?
- And, if not, how could I approach the problem? Should I combine already existing classes or roll my own? (which I wouldn't like to *have* to do at all)

I was considering to use `Observable.Timer` or `Observable.Interval` from Reactive Extensions, but I wouldn't know how to stop/pause/reset it, and also I would rather expose `IObservable<TimesTamp>` instead of `IObservable<long>`.

(update)
Also, there is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16399011/401828) suggesting to measure time with a `StopWatch` and update UI with a quick-ticking `Timer`, but still it feels like a workaround.

Comment: Use the `Timer` as a tick source, not to track the actual elapsed time.  Basically, record the start time, and every tick of the timer (1000 ms), subtract the start time from the current time to get the elapsed time and update the UI.  This method is FAR more accurate that relying on the `Timer` to track the elapsed time directly.  You can easily pause, resume, and reset the timer with this method.

Comment: @BradleyUffner thanks for your feedback! I should have a way to pause the measuring of time also, not only the UI notification. That is, if I pause at 13.456 seconds, and wait for a bunch of seconds, when I start again (unpause) I should restart measuring from where I left. Do you think having a field for that would be acceptable?

Comment: You could track the paused interval the same way and just subtract it from the elapsed time calculation.  You could also have another field to store the previous elapsed time that get incremented by the new elapsed time whenever it gets paused.

Comment: As far as I know, there is no built in component that works *exactly* the way you want.  You will definitely have to build a custom solution.

Comment: I still think the linked solution you have in the question is the best and cleanest choice though.  The `Stopwatch` gives you the best timer resolution, and the ability to pause, while the `Timer` updates the UI.

Comment: Agree. I think I will mark this as duplicate.